# Python cannot bind my external/public IP address using socket, gives error But when using local IP address the error doesn't show up

Tags: python, sockets

Here is the code where the main error shows up

A bind with my local IP will work:

```py
s.bind(("192.168.1.4", port))
```

A bind with my public IP fails with the error below

```py
s.bind(("99.99.99.99", port))
```

> [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Here is more context about my code:

```py
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

port = 6767

try:
    s.bind(("192.168.1.4", port))  # will work fine as local ip is used but 
                                   # when used public ip the error is thrown
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e)+"aa")

s.listen(2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only bind to an IP address which is local to your system. The "public IP" you see is likely not the IP address of your local machine but the IP address of your router which provides you with internet connectivity.

That means you would need to run a program on this router in order to bind to this IP address. Since this is usually impossible the common way to make some internal service accessible from outside is to bind to the address in your local network and then add a forward rule to your router which forwards external connections to your internal IP and port where the service is bound to and listening.

Comment: well i did do the port forwarding on my router. i just want multiple client scripts on different networks(not locally) to connect to server. is this possible in python?

Comment: @BilalB: port forwarding means that the traffic is forwarded to a specific IP and port. You need to bind to this (local) IP and port and not to the public IP. The router translates the data as needed so that they arrive with the local IP as destination at your internal computer but you can still see the external client IP address which connected.

Comment: ok so basically i did was to give local ip and port to server and public ip of where server is running is given in client and than in router i added a forward rule of local ip and port of where server is running and now problem is my client cant connect to server.

Comment: i am rather new in python and networking and i cant seem to find a example that connects to server over the internet all examples shows connecting locally

Comment: @BilalB: Unfortunately, trying to debug router issues is often frustrating. The only advice is to look online for how to do port forwarding for your particular router. Maybe install a program that **requires** port forwarding to work and then when you get it working you'll know how to correctly accomplish port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Some details in addition to the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509798/7733418 :

It is necessary to set up ports on the router to allow all my client data to access the internal ip of my server. And you also have to allow those ports in your firewall.