# Python server using the socket module not working over two devices over two different locations

Tags: python, sockets, server, connection, client

This is my first project working with sockets and unfortunately, it's been quite painful. I'm trying to make a simple chatroom, however, it only ever works when the socket IP is local (e.g. 127.0.0.1). However, when I try to connect to my local IP, it doesn't work. I even had my friend run the client while I ran the server, and on his side, the client froze up for a while until it crashed. The port that I'm using is forwarded and firewall restrictions have been taken care of already. The number is 31400, so that's not the issue either. Here is some of the code from the server:

```
connection_file = open("connection.sav", "r")
connection_info = connection_file.readlines()
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = int(connection_info[1][0:-1])
connection_file.close()

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
server_socket.listen()
```

The port reading is also not an issue, as the integer prints the exact number I am looking for when testing for that. What could possibly be the issue?
Note: The server connects to "127.0.0.1", while the client connects to my public IP.

I've tried setting up yet another port (31401) and tried to connect the server and the client to that, but that didn't work either. I tried sending the client to my friend and letting him connect, but it didn't work either. I've tried connecting the server to my public IP and port, but that just made it crash. The server is properly listening on "127.0.0.1", but the client just won't connect to the public IP. I've looked at tons of posts but none of them seem to have this specific issue.

Comment: You set up the server to accept connections only on the loopback interface. Your client must therefore run on the same machine as the server and can only connect to 127.0.0.1. So, don't do that.

Comment: Okay, assuming you read that my client connects to my public IP, not "127.0.0.1", I said that my server crashes if I try to connect the SERVER program to my public IP, do you know why this may be? This is the error that I get when trying to connect my server to my public IP btw: OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Comment: Bind to `'0.0.0.0'` or `''` to listen on all interfaces. Your public IP is not a server interface.

Answer (score 0):

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509626/python-cannot-bind-my-external-public-ip-address-using-socket-gives-error-but-w) helped me realize the mistake.
I fixed the issue by connecting the server to my machine's IP rather than plain "127.0.0.1" and by connecting the client to my public IP.